# GCP copy files in from VM to local

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud, scp

I'm trying to copy files from my VM to my local computer.

I can do this with the standard command
`sudo gcloud compute scp --recurse orca-1:/opt/test.txt .`

However in downloading the log files they transfer but they're empty?  (empty files are created with the same name)

I'm also unable to use the Cloud Shell 'Download' UI button because it gives `No such file` despite the absolute file path being correct (cat /path returns the data).

I understand it's a permissions thing somehow with log files?

Comment: Are you using Compute Engine or Cloud Shell?

Comment: Which identity do you use in your terminal and what permissions did you give it ?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm using Cloud Shell in the GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies to my thread above I figured out it was a permissions issue on my files.

Interestingly the first time I ran the commands it did not throw any errors or permission errors -- it downloaded all the expected files however they were empty.  In testing again, now it threw permission errors.  I then modified the files in question to have public read permissions, and it downloaded successfully.